# Can I use a round polishing sponge with a delta sander?

Tags: glass, sander, polish

My shower stall has grown to a sorry state, with limescale/scum deposits that won't go away by chemical means (my attempts progressed to 25% HCl before I gave up). So what I want to try now is a mechanical removal with glass polish compound.

Anywhere I look, these compounds are used with polishing pads or sponges mounted on round sanders, or there are adapters for electric screwdrivers. I don't have an electric screwdriver, and I don't have a round sander, but I have a "multifunction" sander with a delta-shaped tip and a horizontal addition below the delta, a bit like a small clothesiron.

The sander plate has the same velcro hooks as the round sander plates, so the polishing pad or sponge would stick to it mechanically. Also, the pad or sponge would be thick enough that any area not covered by the pad would not come in contact with the glass. I could also put some masking tape on top to avoid polishing paste coming into the hooks.

The sander has holes through which wood dust is sucked in, that would be covered by the pad, but I think that the round sanders have those too, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Given that the attachment is physically possible, the question remains, should I do it? Are there risks I haven't thought of, either to the sander or to the shower stall?

Comment: I don't think there's any issue using a sponge-type pad.  Size might be an issue.

Comment: There are no mechanical means I'd use on glass. CLR should do ... the thing it says it does, and ZEP should take care of soap scum. Having to go from my experience of (having to make these myself 30y ago) a rotary pad, to something that simply vibrates... no. Rotary at 3000rpm is way beyond elbow grease, and vibrating... is not.

Comment: >Avoid [CLR] contact with wood, clothing, wallpaper, carpeting, natural stones, brass, copper, aluminum, galvanized metals, any painted, coated or sealed surfaces.

Comment: And this brush. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/258207/23295

Comment: If it doesn't bubble when you apply hydrochloric acid then it is not limescale. Did it bubble?

Comment: @AndrewMorton good point! I don't remember if it did. I tried many power tools and abrasives, and in the end, I managed to get it clean with a sponge mounted on an electric screwdriver combined with car polish liquid.

Comment: @rumtscho Maybe you could add that as answer, and accept it? How quickly did the car polish liquid work - was it a colour restoraration variety or something else?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't think it's an exact answer to the question as aksed, because I didn't use the delta sander after all, but bought an electric screwdriver. For the cleaning part, I'm travelling now and will have to look up the type of polishing compound when I return home. It was somewhat tedious work - I had to go over the same place a few times - but when I was finished, it looked very clean, and there was no noticeable damage to the surface.

Answer (score 1):

They're available for the 'mouse' type sanders, but tough to google "[bosch mouse polishing fleece](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=bosch%20mouse%20polishing%20fleece&i=diy&crid=EE1RIBDEPW0C&sprefix=bosch%20mouse%20polishing%20fleece%2Cdiy%2C74&ref=nb_sb_noss)" eventually worked for me.

They work fine on 'plastic' [polycarbonate] car headlights with either rubbing compound or toothpaste, so I doubt they'll do any damage to real glass.